# How can I change multiple collaborators to "comment only", at once?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, security, google-drive-sharing

If I happen to have many people individually editing a shared folder in Google Drive, how can I easily downgrade everybody's access on files that I add?

The situation in which this would be needed is as follows.
I recently shared a link to a Google Drive folder, with edit access, to about 50 people. (I know that this isn't a good idea to share it with so many people, but I would still need to get them on board with the idea that we should be using a Team Drive (under our institution).) The problem is that when I initially sent out an e-mail with the link, I wasn't aware that some recipients are not part of the class. I would have wanted to renew the link (as with our WhatsApp group), but [that is not possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89758/109353). So, it seems that the next-best solution is to add everybody individually, then downgrade the link from edit access.

A benefit of sharing a regular folder, as opposed to having a Team Drive, is that I (and others) can add personal files in there (Shift + Z), and carry on working on those files from my own folder structure, whilst preventing others from editing them. However, when I share my files there in future, they will automatically take on the sharing settings of the folder it is in. I will find it tedious to change around 40 people from "edit" to "comment" individually, every time I share a file, so **my question is how to change all the people's access to one setting at the same time**.

Comment: Is the [security] tag appropriate? Because, documents that are editable by too many people can be defaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder specifically for your files, then the files you add in there will take on the sharing settings for that folder by default.